# Script Trigger returning dates in US format (en expected)

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this small script as part of a bigger project:

```
//get all trigger values from named ranges containing __
function triggers(e) {
  console.log("redirect");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10JekLhXtlbkEfXJBB7HfIF4t3pyQQpKbPzTCJq0306o/edit#gid=465383306");
  ss.setSpreadsheetLocale('en');
  //const timeNow = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/YYYY").toString();
  const timeNow = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  const triggers = ss.getNamedRanges().reduce( (acc,curr)=>{
           if (curr.getName().indexOf("__")>-1) {acc.push([curr.getName(), curr.getRange().getValue().toLocaleDateString()])}
           return acc;}, []);

console.log(triggers. timeNow);

//call switch function to redirect trigger to associated function
triggers.forEach(x => {if(x[1] == timeNow){triggerRedirs(x[0])}});
}
```

When I run the script manually the values returned are returned as `dd/MM/YYYY` which is correct but when I run the script via a trigger all the dates returned are in the format `MM/dd/YYYY`. I've set the linked spreadsheet locale to UK & the script project timezone is London.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying specifying the locale using `toLocaleDateString('en-GB')`.

```
curr.getRange().getValue().toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
```

[Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)